# Spring Batch StepScope and Proxies. Again

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm trying to save a step-related state, that would be accessible from processor. For this purpose I made a class and a bean for it. My configuration file looks like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class MyConfiguration
{
    // Job, reader and writer beans

    @Bean("myStep")
    Step myStep(@Qualifier("myReader") ItemReader<InputEntity> reader,
            @Qualifier("myProcessor") ItemProcessor<InputEntity, OutputEntity> processor,
            @Qualifier("myWriter") ItemWriter<OutputEntity> writer)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("myStep")
                .<InputEntity, OutputEntity> chunk(100)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean("myProcessor")
    public MyProcessor processingStep(StateService s)
    {
        var processor = new MyProcessor();
        processor.setStateService(s);
        return processor;
    }

    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.NO)
    @Bean
    public StateService stateService()
    {
        return new StateService();
    }

}
```

Idea behind is to create a state service for each new step execution (the class is empty at the moment and doesn't have `@Component` annotation). However, I get in trouble with Spring proxies:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'MyProcessor' is expected to be of type 'very.long.package.name.steps.MyProcessor' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy265'
```

Gathering already answered questions and dozens of guides I tried following:

- All possible proxy modes of `stateService` bean;
- Injecting this bean directly into `MyProcessor` via `@Autowired` variable
- Annotating configuration with `@EnableBatchProcessing`
- Calling `stateService()` bean directly: `processor.setStateService(stateService());`
- Injecting bean into step `Step` bean. In this case I have to change the method signature, so the method accepts `MyProcessor` instead of `ItemProcessor<InputEntity, OutputEntity>` to expose the variable

Nothing helped, I still get this exception. What am I misunderstanding in concept of `@StepScope`?    How can I store some state for particular step execution?

I read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#step-scope), [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/StepScope.html) and even [this](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-batch-in-action), but neither helped me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, adding an interface helps in this case:

```
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@Bean
public IStateService stateService()
{
    return new StateService();
}
```

I also had to add new interface `IStateService`, which I actually don't need. However, it still doesn't answer the question WHY, and doesn't bring any understanding either.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I misunderstanding in concept of @StepScope?

The step scope is designed for beans that should be lazily instantiated at runtime when the step is executed. By default, for interface based beans, Spring will create JDK dynamic proxies, and for classes it will use CGLib.

In the code you shared, you used `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.NO`, so you have explicitly told Spring to not create a proxy for that bean, hence your error. And that's why when you change it to `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES` it works.

> How can I store some state for particular step execution?

The execution context is designed for this very use case (among other use cases). So you can store that state in the `ExecutionContext` of the step and retrieve afterwards in the same job or when restarting a failed job.

Comment: It's not only about changing proxyMode, but about actual addition of an interface, I don't need there. Only changing `proxyMode` to `INTERFACES` doesn't change anything. I tried to play with all other modes — but still no result.

Comment: You don't need an interface. For classes, Spring will use CGlib to create proxies as mentioned in my answer. You should return the most specific type in your bean definition and it should work as expected, as documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#scoping-item-streams.